# Pass list elements as arguments of a function one by one

Tags: python, list, function, parameters, arguments

Suppose I have a function to calculate the square of a certain number. Now, I have a list of, for example, 100 numbers that I need to pass as the arguments. How do I pass each element of the list, one by one, as the argument to get the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop:

```
def square(i):
    return i ** 2


lst = [1,2,3,4,...]
for i in lst:
    result = square(i)
    print(result)
```

This works because the iterator, `i` goes through every element in `lst` and passes it as a parameter into our function, `square()`.

I hope this helped! Let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` loop.

```
yourlist = [1,2,3,4...]
for i in yourlist:
    yourfunction(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def square(num):
        return num ** 2
lt = [1..n]
for i in lt:
        newElement = square(i)
        print(newElement)
```

You can use this or you can append the new element in a new list and print the list of square of original list.

```
nlist = []
for i in list:
      newEle = square(i)
      nlist.append(newEle)
 
print(nlist)
```

You can do it by both ways.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the examples are wrong. First of all, shading built-in names (e.g. list) should be avoided. In your first example the square() function does not calculate the square of the number, but instead raises the integer to the power of its own (e.g. 4^4 = 256, not 16). Also, you're printing the original list, not the result. In addition, in the second example,creating lists of None is useless, instead .append() is preferred. And incrementing i inside for loop will not bring the needed results.